# dynamic parameters in filter api using c#

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hi all I am new in webapi and i am stuck in filter api hope get some solution from here

https://localhost/webservices/catalog/category/57/widgets/paginated?city=Gautam+Buddha+Nagar&pageNumber=0&pageSize=10&sort=relevance

for applying filtering
https://localhost/webservices/catalog/category/57/widgets/paginated?city=Gautam+Buddha+Nagar&pageNumber=0&pageSize=10&gender=Female&product_form=Tablet&sort=relevance

If you see in my api it is same name of api but parameter is different in case how can i handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take parameters as optional parameter. Just you have to remember you cant write necessary parameter after optional parameter -

`[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ABC(string city = null, int? pageNumber = null, int? pageSize = null, string gender = null, string product_form = null, string sort = null){
}`

Comment: Can i handle it using public class abcPrameter{ public string city{ get; set;public int pageNumber { get; set; } ,etc}

Comment: Definitely you can do that. Take all parameters as a model (class) also you can validate the paramters using modelState.Isvalid property. Accept answer if it works for u.